# How do I test controllers with Angular Translate initialized in App Config?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I have an app that uses Angular Translate (https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate). Translate works great in the application via browser but when I try to test any controller I get **Error: Unexpected request: GET locale/locale-en.json**. How do I unit test my controllers since translate does a GET request for the language file on startup?

I am using the yeoman angular generator with Karma.

---

App.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

      $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'locale/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
      });
      $translateProvider.uses('en');
      $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
  });
```

Controller Test:

```
describe('Controller: DocumentationCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var DocumentationCtrl,
    scope,
    $httpBackend;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    DocumentationCtrl = $controller('DocumentationCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('locale/locale-en.json').respond(200, {
      "TITLE": 'My App'
    });
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

The Documentation Controller is just a standard generated controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the preferred language within config phase rather then run phase. So `$translate.uses('us')` becomes `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('us')`. 
Same goes for `useLocalStorage()`. These are all methods to configure `$translate` service.

You should also try to avoid `uses()` to set a default language. Use `preferredLanguage()` instead. The reason for this is, that `$translate.uses()`  tries to load a i18n file as soon as possible,
if there's a cookie or similar which uses another language key, `uses()` will load two files, that why we introduced `preferredLanguage()` And yea, this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I am still not sure how to test this although I did switch to preferredLanguage() so my app.config looks like this: $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'locale/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
      });
      $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('us');
      $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

Comment: Oh and the error occurs because you're not expecting an http get request explitly. So in your it() spec you should do something like: $http.expectGET('locale/locale-us.json'); And don't forget to flush the pending reponses via $http.flush();

Comment: I got it working. The fix was to use preferredLanguage() and override the function before initializing the app in my unit test. This is a sizeable app and I did not want to put the locale expectGET in every single unit test. Thanks!

Comment: When overwriting `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage()` internally, no language is set, since you also don't set the language via `$translateProvider.uses()` anymore. This means no 18n file will ever be loaded and then no "Unexpected GET request" error is firing. This again would mean, your test doesn't really test what you want to test.

And to be honest, you actually don't have to test the functionality of angular-translate (by checking if the i18n file is really loaded) since these tests are coming with angular-translate itself.

Comment: @PascalPrecht What do you suggest then? It seems that (with loader-static-files at least) the request for the json file comes during the module config which is before any of your unit tests are run. How do you suggest mocking this http request?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20082591/2165552 seems to provide some good guidance on a general approach to solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

Avoid initialize application level module, put your controllers in myApp.controllers and test this module instead.

"We recommend that you break your application to multiple modules. (...) The reason for this breakup is that in your tests, it is often necessary to ignore the initialization code, which tends to be difficult to test."

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: I did try that and it still seems the way to go but the issue remains the same with the unexpected GET /locale/en-us.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong order: The setup for angular-translate tries to loading the language right after calling `uses(lang)` (after the block, indeed).

We had similar problems when developing the adapters in anguluar-translate. Try to look into https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate-loader-url/blob/16e559030bce819e8ca1b82fed7163286b57bafe/test/unit/translateUrlLoaderSpec.js which are the tests for the url loader plugin.

Should the controller not be injected a step later?

Comment: I was thinking that as well, however I have tried putting expectGET/whenGET in several different positions. The problem I think is what you may be eluding to which is that it is a chicken and egg problem. Basically I need to define the whenGET before the app runs, but the app needs instantiated first. Any examples of how to accomplish that? Do I need to load translate in my test first, then my app?