# How do unit test with angular-translate

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, yeoman, karma-runner

I have uses angular translate from here (http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/) and it's just work fine, but it break my controller's unit test whith Error:

```
Unexpected request: GET scripts/i18n/locale-en.json
```

I don't understant why?

I use yeoman and test with karma.

app.js:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  angular.module('wbApp', ['authService', 'authUserService', 'checkUserDirective', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl',
          access: {
            isFree: true
          }
        })
        .when('/main', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          access: {
            isFree: false
          }
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });

})();
```

configTranslate.js:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  angular.module('wbApp')
    .config(['$translateProvider',
      function($translateProvider) {

        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'scripts/i18n/locale-',
            suffix: '.json'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

      }]);

})();
```

karma.conf.js:

```
files = [

  ...

  'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',

  ...

];
```

controller test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('wbApp'));

  var LoginCtrl, scope, location, httpMock, authUser;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location, $httpBackend, AuthUser) {
    authUser = AuthUser;
    location = $location;
    httpMock = $httpBackend;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    LoginCtrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });


    httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').passThrough();

  }));

  it(...);

  ...

});
```

if i add this in test controller, product same error:

```
httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').respond(200);
httpMock.flush();
```

or

```
httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').passThrough();
httpMock.flush();
```

i find this post [How do I test controllers with Angular Translate initialized in App Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345928/how-do-i-test-controllers-with-angular-translate-initialized-in-app-config/18874667#18874667) but not helped me :/

I extensively use $httpBackend in my tests and it works fine, but in this case it is ineffective. If I comment the line:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

obviously an error, if I add on the runtime (in my controllers)

```
$translate.uses(local);
```

I end up with the same error?

So I turn to the translation configuration (configTranslate.js) or at runtime is the same result:

```
Unexpected request: GET scripts/i18n/locale-en.json
```

Here is the syntax that I tested, either in a "beforeEach(inject(function(...});"

or in a test "it('...', function() {...});"

```
httpMock.expectGET('scripts/i18n/locale-en.json');
httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').passThrough();
httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').respond(data);
```

with at end

```
httpMock.flush();
```

I also tried a $ apply

```
httpMock.expectGET('scripts/i18n/locale-fr.json');
scope.$apply(function(){
  $translate.uses('fr');
});
httpMock.flush();
```

nothing happens, Still this error is driving me crazy ..

If you have any suggestion

Comment: Error message says that it received `scripts/i18n/locale-en.json.` see the extra dot at the end? Is it a typo, or a real message? because you are expecting requests without dot in the end, so it might be the cause of the problem

Comment: thank for answering, but it's my fault, the dot at end it's just a typo... corrected

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that $translateProvider makes the http call to get the json file once the app module's config method is called. Since this is during app setup it seems it's a chicken and egg problem trying to insert the http stub. I'm currently researching a solution to this myself.

Comment: Anyone found a solution?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287223/how-to-deal-with-angular-modules-config-function-when-unit-testing/20082591  for the solution I used

Answer (score 28):

it's a known issue, please follow the documentation here: [unit testing angular](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/22_unit-testing-with-angular-translate)

> **The solution**
>
> Unfortunately, this issue is caused by the design of
>   angular-translate. To get around these errors, all we can do is to
>   overwrite our module configuration in our test suite, that it doesn't
>   use asynchronous loader at all. When there's no asynchronous loader,
>   there's no XHR and therefore no error.
>
> So how do we overwrite our module configuration at runtime for our
>   test suite? When instantiating an angular module, we can always apply
>   a inline function which is executed as configuration function. This
>   configuration function can be used to overwrite the modules
>   configuration since we have access to all providers.
>
> Using the $provide provider, we can build a custom loader factory,
>   which should then be used instead of the static files loader.

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide, $translateProvider) {

  $provide.factory('customLoader', function () {
    // loader logic goes here
  });

  $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader');

}));
```

Please read more in the above link provided.

Comment: That solution is not really bearable. I've still to declare this for every test. Is there an open issue about that?

Comment: I concur with hugo, testing code that uses callable angular services in general (not only $translate but also $timeout and $interval) is pretty inconvenient. Each solution requires a special trick (like $timeout.flush()) to get a half-way sound test. As far as I know (I'm just a beginner but that is my opinion so far) all tests for these services rely heavily on the fact that the services behave correctly. Should for any reason one of these services be broken, my test cases would break although the code they are supposed to test is working correctly.

Answer (score 15):

We took the approach of ignoring the translation loader in unit tests, rather than being forced to modify each of the spec files.

One way to do it could be by separating the loader configuration to a separate file and then exclude it in karma.

So for example you can create a file app-i18n-loader.js (all other module configurations takes place in a different file):

```
    angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(loaderConfig);

loaderConfig.$inject = ['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider'];

function loaderConfig($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'assets/i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
    });

    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('myApp');
}
```

And in your karma.conf.js exclude the file:

```
        files: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        //...
        'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
        'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js',
        'app/**/*.mdl.js',
        'app/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
        'app/app-i18n-loader.js'
    ],
```

(Note: Answer edited to a solution that does not require grunt/gulp).

Answer (score 13):

I wanted a solution,

1. which was not too hacky
2. which didn't require me to change my actual application code,
3. which wouldn't interfere with the ability to load additional modules
4. and most importantly which wouldn't require me to change every
   single test.

This is what I ended up with:

```
// you need to load the 3rd party module first
beforeEach(module('pascalprecht.translate'));
// overwrite useStaticFilesLoader to get rid of request to translation file
beforeEach(module(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader = function () {
    };
}));
```

Assuming you don't need the actual translations for your unit tests, this works great. Just put the beforeEach on a global level, preferably in it's own file inside the test folder. It will be executed before every other test then.

Comment: Works well with places where you are testing the usage of the translate service, but not the translations themselves. I ended up calling $translateProvider.translations('en'.... in the relevant tests (where testing that a httpInterceptor triggered the correct error message alerts messages, and defaulted to a generic one)

Comment: $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader = function () { return $translateProvider; //For Chaining
    };

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem with protractor tests. My solution was to mock translations like this:

```
angular.module('app')
        .config(function ($translateProvider) {
            $translateProvider.translations('en', {});
            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
        })
```

Now no language files are downloaded, no strings get translated and I just test against the string keys in specifications:

```
expect(element(by.css('#title')).getText()).toEqual('TITLE_TEXT');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting to test method:

```
it('should ...', function() {
    httpMock.when('GET', 'scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').respond({});
    httpMock.expectGET('scripts/i18n/locale-en.json');
    scope.resetForm(); // Action which fires a http request
    httpMock.flush(); // Flush must be called after the http request
}
```

See examples from [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)

Comment: this is what I also did but no change? i also test with `httpMock.flush();` after..

Comment: Could you paste your full test code to http://jsfiddle.net/? I can see if I can help.

Comment: yes of course, you will find the code for my loginCtrl here:
http://jsfiddle.net/s88EX/

Comment: unfortunately it does not work either. Incredible, I am the only one with this 'bug'? I feel that the command:
`translateProvider.preferredLanguage $ ('en');`
xhr that causes this long before the tests are instantiated and the chance to intercept via
`httpMock.when (...) or httpMock.expectGET (...)`

Comment: Does it help if you override the function on `beforeEach`: `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage = function(){}`? You should of course inject `$translateProvider`.

Comment: @MattiLehtinen The problem with this approach is that any hacking you to do intercept that message and prevent the http call is localized to one spot. What if you wanted to comment out that test and run a test on say just one filter? Or a different controller? Without that mocking stuff, as soon as you try to inject anything from your app module anywhere, it will run module.config which will make the http call and break.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/blob/master/test/unit/service/loader-static-files.spec.js as a reference.

In general, I would recommend using a standard translation loader for unit tests (without the hassle of http loadings) which means you can provide the labels with `$translateProvider.translations()`. Why? Because you do not have to test the remote loading functionality which is part of angular-translate project.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me but I came with these solutions:

1) If you need to use `scope.$apply()`, or should deal with states in your test (after the `$apply()` the 2nd approach won't work), override your app's translations with the `$translateProvider.translations()` method, using a plugin to [load JSON files](https://github.com/pizzapanther/Karma-Read-JSON)

```
beforeEach(module(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', readJSON('scripts/i18n/locale-en.json'));
}));
```

2) If your tested controller depends on the `$translate` service you can use a plugin to [load JSON files](https://github.com/pizzapanther/Karma-Read-JSON) and combine it with `$httpBackend` to load your locale file when angular-translate requests it.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    $httpBackend.whenGET('scripts/i18n/locale-en.json').respond(readJSON('scripts/i18n/locale-en.json'));
    $httpBackend.flush();
})));
```

Note this should be below your `beforeEach(module('myApp'));` or you will get an `$injector` error.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple mock service for $translate

```
$translate=function (translation) {
    return {
      then: function (callback) {
        var translated={};
        translation.map(function (transl) {
          translated[transl]=transl;
        });
        return callback(translated);
      }
    }
  };
```

Usage example here : https://gist.github.com/dam1/5858bdcabb89effca457

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern.

- ApplicationModule set regular angular-translate config.
- test code load 'testModule' instead of 'applicationModule'

```js
// application module .js 
(function() {
  'use strict'; 
  
  angular
   .module('applicationModule', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider', config]);

  function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    // set routing ... 
        
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'i18n/locale-',
      suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.useMessageFormatInterpolation();
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage(['en']);
    $translateProvider
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'ko'], {
      'en_US': 'en',
      'ko_KR': 'ko'
    })
    .determinePreferredLanguage(navigator.browserLanguage);

            
    $translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');    
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
  }

})();
```

```js
// test.module.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('testModule', ['applicationModule'])
    .config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider', config])
    .run(['$httpBackend', run]);

  function config($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'i18n/locale-en.json'
    });
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('applicationModule');
  }

  function run($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'i18n/locale-en.json').respond(200);
  }

})();


// someDirective.spec.js
describe("a3Dashboard", function() {
    beforeEach(module("testModule"))

    var element, $scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        element = angular.element("<div>{{2 + 2}}</div>");
        $compile(element)($rootScope)
    }))

    it('should equal 4', function() {
      $scope.$digest();
      expect(element.html()).toBe("4");
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the table with this, but I got round this by specifying that Karma simply serve the files as per this entry in `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
    ...
    {pattern: 'scripts/i18n/*.json', included: false, served: true},
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2016 answer for this is to preprocess your json into your tests and properly test translations work on your directives.

I use karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor. Follow all the steps to setup your karma.conf then in your test file, prepend the relevant file as a module, then set that information in $translateProvider.

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', '/l10n/english-translation.json'));

// Mock translations for this template
beforeEach(module(function($translateProvider, englishTranslation) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en_us', englishTranslation);
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_us');
}));
```

Note according to the plugin, it uses your filename to generate a camelcased module name.  You can play with the function inside the module's /lib but basically it remove all dashes but KEEPS underscores in a camelCase.  So en_us becomes En_us.

You'll also need to tell your test that it is expecting that file as a GEt.

```
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/l10n/english-translation.json').respond(200);
```