# Unit testing an AngularJS app that uses $translatePartialLoaderProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-translate

I am designing the unit tests for an AngularJS web app, using Karma-Jasmine.
The web app uses angular-translate and, specifically, employs the **$translatePartialLoaderProvider** module. The app itself works well; however, the unit tests fail with the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.view1 due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translatePartialLoaderProvider
```

I have followed the unit-testing instructions for angular-translate available at http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/22_unit-testing-with-angular-translate, as mentioned in [Question #18876290](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate), yet the unit tests still fail with the above-mentioned error.

A code sample illustrating the error is available here (Plunker):
http://embed.plnkr.co/8X7diP/. Note that the app works well: you can switch views and the view text is translated as expected. As soon as you remove **$translatePartialLoaderProvider** in view1mod.js, the app passes the test.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, even though your `app.js` has the `translate` dependency, your `view1` or `view2` modules don't, i.e. this will fix the spec -

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
```

You'll have to fix this in both `view1mod.js` and `view2mod.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, FrailWords. It worked.

Comment: @Francisco - happy to help.