# $scope.$apply is throwing 'Unexpected request: No more request expected' in Mocha Sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, karma-mocha

I have service A which calls another services B and in turn B which has $http injected call the API web-service.

Now when i tried to stub service B using Mocha Sinon I am getting the following error

> Unexpected request: GET app/contract/forecast/il8n/en.json  No more
>   request expected

Note I am not using httpBackend anywhere in my code.

Code is as follow

```
var somePromise = B.getData(url,data);
somepromise.then(success, failed);
```

Test Code is

```
it('Testing A.loadCustomerInformation', function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       var promise = deferred.promise;
       sinon.stub(B,'getData').returns(promise);
       deferred.resolve({data : customerInformation});
       A.loadCustomerInformation(vm);
       rootScope.$apply();
       assert(B.getData.called);
       assert(A.someotherMtd1.called);
       assert(A.someotherMtd2.called);
});
```

Basically i want to stub service B function 'getData' and return mock response and check the vm(view model) object populated correctly against mock input.

I have following configuration

> Gulp, Karma, phantom js, Mocha, Sinon etc..

Help is appreciated!

Comment: My guess not knowing the full code is, that `loadCustomerInformation` is using `ngTranslate` somewhere, which loads your english translations as request.

Comment: How can we restrict it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate

Comment: It's worked after following the link mention by @Chasmo which basically talk about this (http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/22_unit-testing-with-angular-translate) link. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i commented above, by following [Unit Testing with Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/22_unit-testing-with-angular-translate)
which i got from @Chasmo [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate) things set up nicely.. Following is the code i added

`beforeEach(module('app', function ($provide, $translateProvider) {
          $provide.factory('testLoader', function ($q) {
              return function () {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  deferred.resolve({});
                  return deferred.promise;
                };
          });
          $translateProvider.useLoader('testLoader');
        }));`