# Possibly unhandled rejection in a karma unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

I use jasmine to write a unit test for a controller, where I have to check whether a function worked on `$scope.$watch`. I use `'controller as'` syntax, but I've injected `$scope` to create a watcher. However, my test throws a vague exception on `$scope.$apply()`. Here's my controller:

```
OrderController.$inject = ['Order', 'cart',
    '$mdDialog', '$state', '$rootScope', '$scope'];

function OrderController(Order, cart, $mdDialog, $state, $rootScope, $scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.order = new Order({
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        address: ''
    });
    vm.order.items = [];
    vm.promoCode = '';
    vm.order.promo_code = false;

    $scope.$watch('vm.promoCode', function () {
        if (vm.promoCode && vm.promoCode == 'm7e17')) {
            vm.order.promo_code = true;
        }
    }); }
```

And here's my test:

```
describe('Order Controller', function () {
var OrderController, CartService, $scope;
var item = {};
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.services'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _cart_, $state, $mdDialog) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    CartService = _cart_;
    CartService.add(item);
    OrderController = $controller('OrderController',
        {
            $scope: $scope,
            $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
            cart: CartService,
            $state: $state,
            $mdDialog: $mdDialog
        }
    );
}));

it('Should save a boolean whether a promo code has been entered', function () {
    expect(OrderController.order.promo_code).toBe(false);
    OrderController.promoCode = 'm7e17';
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(OrderController.order.promo_code).toBe(true);
});         });
```

However, when I call `$scope.$apply` inside my spec, it throws an error: `'Possibly unhandled rejection: ru thrown'`. Could not find anything about it on the internet so, what I am I doing wrong here? I have other tests using the scope too, but they don't fail (though not calling `$scope.$apply` inside them), how can this be fixed?

Comment: AngularJS version?

Comment: @tasseKATT it's angular 1.5.9

Comment: Same error if you remove the injection of `$mdDialog` and `$state` in the controller?

Comment: @tasseKATT yes, it actually was there all the time, i tried to add those dependencies and see whether they are the subtle cause of trouble, but it seems not.

Comment: Will try to reproduce.

Comment: You can try adding some of your stuff here to see if you can reproduce it: http://plnkr.co/edit/TvzxhZFcOOgUw4LBQq1z?p=preview

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with `ui-router`.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2889

Comment: @tasseKATT I just don't really understand how the ui-router issue takes place when $scope.$apply is called.

Comment: When calling `$apply` the digest loop is triggered, all promise callbacks will be resolved, Angular will detect an unhandled rejection and throw the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had recently the same issue.(Only with ' Possibly unhandled rejection: en thrown')
This issue is caused by the design of angular-translate, i assume you use this in your app.
Have a look at the following link:
[How do unit test with angular-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate)

There are some approaches to solve this issue.
I used the one which extracts the config of the translationProvider in an own file and in karma i exclude this one.

```
angular.module('qPro5App').config(loaderConfig);

loaderConfig.$inject = ['$translateProvider'];

function loaderConfig($translateProvider) {

// translation i18n support
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  files: [{
    prefix: 'assets/i18n/errors-',
    suffix: '.json'
  }, 
  {
    prefix: 'assets/i18n/ui-',
    suffix: '.json'
  }]
});

$translateProvider
  .preferredLanguage('en')
  .fallbackLanguage('en')
  .useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
}
```

and in karma:

```
exclude: ['app/config/app-i18n-loader.js'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a slightly different context (handling a promise) and added

```
.catch(angular.noop)
```

which fixed the problem.