# How to deal with angular module's config function when unit testing?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When setting up a unit test suite for an angular application using Karma/Jasmine, is it recommended to include the js with the app module's `config` function in the test's files?

I've read that it is suggested to exclude this from testing, however that seems awkward because there's often critical setup that happens in the `config` function that would prevent the application from working.

What's the best practice around this? Create a mock config function that does the same thing in a 'mocked' manner?

I'm running across this issue myself but want to understand the broader strategy:
[How do unit test with angular-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate)

Answer (score 3):

In my application, I ended up using the following solution:

Define an "appBase" module with all the `config` and `run` functions that I want to run when unit-testing and create another "app" module which declares "appBase" module as a dependency and includes all the `config` and `run` functions that I don't what to run when unit-testing. Then all my unit tests use the "appBase" module, while the final application uses the "app" module. In code:

```
angular.module('appBase', ['dependencies'])
       .config(function() {
            // This one will run when unit-testing. Can also set-up mock data
            // that will later be overridden by the "app" module
        });

angular.module('app', ['appBase'])
       .config(function() {
            // This function will only run in real app, not in unit-tests.
       });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that any controllers, directives, etc. that you defined on the `app` module would be untestable? Do you use other modules for all your components and then declare them as dependencies to `appBase`?