# AngularJS: Unit Test Coverage of Promises in Config Blocks

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a config block with a Promise/Resolve in a controller. The controllers is fully covered, but the block is still red. Code blocks of similar patterns are present in various places in our code base and effecting our coverage badly , Any workaround is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The untested bit seems to be your resolve function.  I would write a test that asserts the route provider has this route and then just call the resolve.loadedFeedback method

Comment: @JonSamwell Thats exactly my problem, I am not able to call resolve.loadedFeedback method. If you can direct me to an example that would be great.

Comment: This shouldn't be too tricky - I'm have a look this weekend :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with angular module's config function when unit testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287223/how-to-deal-with-angular-modules-config-function-when-unit-testing)