# AngularJS: Testing registered controllers with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I'm fed up with running unit tests with my AngularJS application using Karma an Jasmine. I'm not using *requireJS*, but custom solution with dynamic loading controllers based on loading widgets segments. Is there any ways to perform a mock or injection of **$controllerProvider** in some pre-loaded test-helper.js?

My typically controller looks like:

```js
'use strict'; 

Polygons.app.controllerProvider.register('MyController',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'MyService'
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, MyService) {
      ...
    }
  ]
);
```

**Polygons.app** is concept wich is described in app.js:

```js
Polygons.app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', '$routeSegmentProvider', '$locationProvider', '$controllerProvider', 'router', '$provide', 
function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider, $routeSegmentProvider, $locationProvider, $controllerProvider, router, $provide) {
  Polygons.app.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
  Polygons.app.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
  ...
```

Because module.config() doesn't execute during tests there is no way to obtain **controllerProvider** property of **Polygons.app** - I'm getting an error *'Cannot read property 'register' of undefined'*.
So is there any ways to solve that problem?
Please, any help or conjecture, I'm totally lost.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with angular module's config function when unit testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287223/how-to-deal-with-angular-modules-config-function-when-unit-testing)