# Jasmine testing AngularJs app that uses angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, jasmine, angular-translate

I have an AngularJs application where I use angular-translate and I want to test the functionality.

I have an i18n module that looks like this:

```
angular.module('i18n', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    'use strict';

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/src/resources/languages/',
        suffix: '.lang.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv');
}]);
```

I also have a service in this module where I use $translate.use() to get and set the current language.

I run into problems when trying to test this..
My test file looks like this:

```
beforeEach(module('i18n'));
it('test', inject(function ($injector, $translate) {
    var i18nService = $injector.get('i18nService');
    console.log('$translate.use(): ', $translate.use());
    console.log('before set: ', i18nService.getLanguage());
    i18nService.setLanguage('en');
    console.log('after set: ', i18nService.getLanguage());
}));
```

and my output from this is:

```
$translate.use(): undefined
before set: undefined
after set: undefined
```

If I remove the

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/src/resources/languages/',
    suffix: '.lang.json'
});
```

from my module, the output is

```
$translate.use(): sv
before set: sv
after set: en
```

I tried use $httpBackend like in these questions:

[How do I test controllers with Angular Translate initialized in App Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345928/how-do-i-test-controllers-with-angular-translate-initialized-in-app-config)

[How do unit test with angular-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876290/how-do-unit-test-with-angular-translate)

but it didn't work..
I don't get any Unexpected request errors like in those questions though.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Thanks!