# angular-translate with angular-mocks results in blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-mock

I'm trying to mock a request/response using ngMock and get this error: `Unexpected request: GET /locales/en_us.json`. After digging around I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345928/how-do-i-test-controllers-with-angular-translate-initialized-in-app-config) on how to get around the error. Adding `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_us')` fixed the error but the templates aren't rendering i.e., I just see a blank page. In the run method I have the following:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(env.baseUri + '/1.0/test-data').respond(function(method, url, data){
return [200, [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test name",7,
        "version": "1.0"
    }
]]
```

In the config method:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_us');
```

EDIT I fixed this error by adding a passThrough for "locales":

```
myAppDev = angular.module('myAppDev', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
myAppDev.run(function($httpBackend) {
  phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}];


  // adds a new phone to the phones array
  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data) {
    var phone = angular.fromJson(data);
    phones.push(phone);
    return [200, phone, {}];
  });
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/locales\//).passThrough();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add $httpBackend.whenGET(/^/locales//).passThrough(); see above.